# Error: Element 'assert' Is Invalid, Misplaced, Or Occurs Too Often

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-parsing, xsd-validation, xsd-1.1

I have tried assert in XSD and I get the error

> Element 'assert' Is Invalid, Misplaced, Or Occurs Too Often.

My example is the below XML.

```html
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<p:CustomerElement xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <recordCount>1234</recordCount>
  <Customer>
      <indicator>A</indicator>
      <test1>hdjfs</test1>
      <test2>idsfh</test2>
   <test3>idsfh</test3>
   <test4>idsfh</test4>
   <test5>idsfh</test5>
   <test6>idsfh</test6>
   <test7>idsfh</test7>
 </Customer>
    <Customer>
      <indicator>D</indicator>
      <test1>abcd</test1>
   <test3>jhf</test3>
    </Customer>
</p:CustomerElement>`
```

The XSD that I created for this is

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" 
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
           xmlns="http://My.Schema.Namespace" 
           targetNamespace="http://My.Schema.Namespace"
     xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning"
           elementFormDefault="qualified"
           vc:minVersion="1.1">>

  <xs:element name="customer">
    <xs:complexType>
 <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="indicator">
 <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="A" />
            <xs:enumeration value="B" />
          </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
   </xs:element>
      <xs:choice>
        <xs:element name="test1" />
        <xs:element name="test2" />
  <xs:element name="test3" />
  <xs:element name="test4" />
  <xs:element name="test5" />
  <xs:element name="test6" />
  <xs:element name="test7" />
      </xs:choice>
   </xs:sequence>
    <xs:assert test="if(indicator eq 'A') then test1 and test2 and test3 and test4 
      and test5 and test6 and test7
      else if(indicator eq 'B') then test1 and test3"/>
 </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
 </xs:schema>
```

I am validating this above xml with XSD in [freeformat validator](http://www.freeformatter.com/xml-validator-xsd.html).

There are few errors in the syntax of assert i guess. Can anyone please help on the condition i was looking for and help me also on syntax and also let me know if i have added the correct links that support XSD 1.1 schema.

Comment: @kjhughes Can you please help me this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve the problems with your XSD:

1. Change

   ```
      elementFormDefault="qualified"
      vc:minVersion="1.1">>
   ```

   to

   ```
      vc:minVersion="1.1">
   ```

   to eliminate the spurious `>` and the duplicated `elementFormDefault` attribute.
2. Add an `else false()` to your assertion test so that it is well-formed.  Better yet, *re-write to the logical equivalent without the compound `if-else` construction.*
3. Use an XSD ***1.1*** processor if you wish to use `xs:assert`.  [Freeformat.com](https://www.freeformatter.com/xml-validator-xsd.html) only supports XSD **1.0**.

### Well-formed XSD

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" 
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
  xmlns="http://My.Schema.Namespace" 
  targetNamespace="http://My.Schema.Namespace"
  xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning"
  vc:minVersion="1.1">

  <xs:element name="customer">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="indicator">
          <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
              <xs:enumeration value="A" />
              <xs:enumeration value="B" />
            </xs:restriction>
          </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:choice>
          <xs:element name="test1" />
          <xs:element name="test2" />
          <xs:element name="test3" />
          <xs:element name="test4" />
          <xs:element name="test5" />
          <xs:element name="test6" />
          <xs:element name="test7" />
        </xs:choice>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:assert test="if (indicator eq 'A') 
        then test1 and test2 and test3 and test4 and test5 and test6 and test7
        else if (indicator eq 'B') then test1 and test3 else false()"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Achieving validity of your XML against this XSD is left as an exercise for the asker to complete, assuming the above obstacles can be overcome.

Comment: @MichaelKay: Good catch.  Fixed.  Thank you!

Comment: @kjhughes Thank you so munch for the solution! Is there any way that can this be optimized? <xs:assert test="if (indicator eq 'A') 
        then test1 and test2 and test3 and test4 and test5 and test6 and test7
        else if (indicator eq 'B') then test1 and test3 else false()"/>
Like instead of mentioning all columns can we make it small as in my real case i have around 100 columns?

Comment: Logic can be re-written: implies can be converted to negation and disjunction, Boolean algebra can simplify, etc.  However, you've not stated your high level goal, so I'm not about to chase the wrong end of an XY-problem.  Since I've helped you past your posted question, please [**accept**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/234215) this answer first.  Then, ask a new question about how to handle your 100 column problem, and be sure to be clear on your high-level goal in your new question.  Thanks.

Comment: @kjhughes hey, can you please help me on this. [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51728413/assert-condition-to-optimize-the-query-in-xsd)   Thanks