# Assert condition to optimize the query in XSD

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-parsing, xsd-validation, xsd-1.1

I have an XSD where i have to use assert condition. I would want to print all columns for condition when indicator='A' and few columns another condition is indicator='D'. I have the below logic but i have around 100 columns so can anyone help me with optimizing the query?

```html
<xs:assert test="if (indicator eq 'A') 
        then test1 and test2 and test3 and test4 and test5 and test6 and test7
        else if (indicator eq 'B') then test1 and test3 
        else false()"/>
```

The input XML is in this format:

```html
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<p:CustomerElement xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <recordCount>1234</recordCount>
  <Customer>
      <indicator>A</indicator>
      <test1>hdjfs</test1>
      <test2>idsfh</test2>
   <test3>idsfh</test3>
   <test4>idsfh</test4>
   <test5>idsfh</test5>
   <test6>idsfh</test6>
   <test7>idsfh</test7>
 </Customer>
    <Customer>
      <indicator>B</indicator>
      <test1>abcd</test1>
      <test2></test2>
   <test3>uydshjk</test3>
   <test4></test4>
   <test5></test5>
   <test6></test6>
   <test7></test7>
    </Customer>
</p:CustomerElement>
```

So as i mentioned when A then all columns populate and when B only 2 columns. If in case i have written the condition wrong, please help me on using which condition to use.

The values for indicator is A or B only for sure.

Thanks.

Comment: @kjhughes hi, hope you are doing great! Can you please help me out on this one! Thanks

Comment: See below.  Please accept if useful to you.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To simplify

```
<xs:assert test="if (indicator eq 'A') 
              then test1 and test2 and test3 and test4 and test5 and test6 and test7
              else if (indicator eq 'B') then test1 and test3 
              else false()"/>
```

given this statement,

> The values for indicator is A or B only for sure.

allow the `else` to cover the `B` case:

```
<xs:assert test="if (indicator eq 'A') 
              then test1 and test2 and test3 and test4 and test5 and test6 and test7
              else test1 and test3"/>
```

Next, given this statement [emphasis added],

> when A then ***all*** columns populate and when B only 2 columns

to avoid having to enumerate ***all*** of `test1` through `test7` (especially given that you mentioned,

> i have around 100 columns

just constrain the total count of  `test1` through `test7` in the assertion,

```
<xs:assert test="if (indicator eq 'A') 
                 then (count(*) = 8)
                 else test1 and test3"/>
```

This will be no less strict than enumerating them if you've already declared their existence explicitly in the content model of `parent`.

As one last step, you might re-write `if else` to the logically equivalent,

```
<xs:assert test="   (indicator eq 'A' and count(*) = 8)
                 or (test1 and test3)"/>
```

but preference for this form over its predecessor is mostly a matter of taste.